# JavaScript Split & jQuery .val() can I chain them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's a very simple question... can I add/chain the JS method `.split()` to jQuery's `.val()` method? For example...

```
var myNewArray =  $("#myString").val().split(",");
```

I seem to get `$("#myString").val().split` is not a function in Firebug? I thought I could chain my JS and jQuery methods, perhaps I was wrong?

Thanks

Comment: That depends on what `$("#myString").val()` returns which in return depends on what the element with ID `myString` is. If the return value is a string, then of course yes. If it is an array, then no.

Comment: What kind of HTML element are you doing `.val()` on? The behaviour of `.val()` may vary. Specifically it may return `null` for a `<select>` that allows multiple selections if there are no selected options.

Comment: So we#re saying I should check that $("#myString").val() isn't a null falsy (I should check it isn't null before splitting).

Comment: For me, your code works fine. See demo http://jsfiddle.net/dwF9t/

Comment: prof http://jsfiddle.net/eD75c/1/

Comment: @Mike: No, not in general. If you know what kind of element `#myString` is and you know that it exists and you know that it returns a string, then you are fine.

Comment: I think I know my original problem here, I wasn't returning a string... when doing a typeof() I notice I#m returning an Object (which is an array) as the $("#myString") is pointing to a multiple select menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you have a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/)? It says:

> Returns: String, Number, Array

So you can use `.split()` in 30% (to be more precise: 33.33...%) of the cases. It depends on which element you are using `.val()` on.

So the answer to your question is: It depends.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can the `val()` return a string so its not jQuery when chaining after that , check the jquery refrence , and about chaining jquery with javascript the answer is no in most cases , because most jquery methods returns a jquery object not a DOM element or primitive javascript type , but in this case your returning a string , so everything should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your selector can't find an element and it returns an empty jQuery object. When you call `val()` method on this object you'll get `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .val().split(",").
But I have question what is in #myString. If it is label then you have to write like this :

```
$(#myString).text().split(" ");
```